# Flex grid div changes width when table inside

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex grid with 2 columns. The columns should has proportionally fixed width 70% (`main-content`) and 30% (`side-content`) and for that I've used the `flex` property accordingly:

```
.content {
    padding-top: 5px;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.main-content {
    flex: 2;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.side-content {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

My problem arises when I put a table inside the `side-content`. For some reason the widths are changed and I loose the 70/30 proportioality. Here is the code:

```
<div class='content'>
  <div class='main-content'>
  THIS IS A MAIN CONTENT AREA THAT SHOUDN'T CHANGE WIDTH
  </div>
  <div class='side-content'>
  THIS IS A SIDE CONTENT AREA THAT SHOUDN'T CHANGE WIDTH

  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the `side-content` div not to expand in any condition, always keeping the 70/30 relation ?

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sgh9zodp/)

Comment: An initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. This means that items cannot be smaller than their content. You can override this default with `min-width: 0` or `overflow` with any value other than `visible`. https://jsfiddle.net/sgh9zodp/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood how Flexbox works, and neither of your samples keep the same relation (70%/30%), and if you size the first enough you'll see they don't.

The reason is the `min-width`, which defaults to `auto` and prevent a flex items to be smaller than its content.

Change your rules to this if you want 70%/30%

```
.main-content {
  flex: 0 0 70%;                   /*  changed  */
  background-color: yellow;
  min-width: 0;                    /*  added  */
}

.side-content {
  flex: 0 0 30%;                   /*  changed  */
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 0;                    /*  added  */
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.content {
  padding-top: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main-content {
  flex: 0 0 70%;                   /*  changed  */
  background-color: yellow;
  min-width: 0;                    /*  added  */
}

.side-content {
  flex: 0 0 30%;                   /*  changed  */
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 0;                    /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<h2>
Normal behaviour
</h2>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='main-content'>
    MAIN CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class='side-content'>
    SIDE CONTENT
  </div>
</div>


<h2>
Not proportional content
</h2>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='main-content'>
    THIS IS A MAIN CONTENT AREA THAT SHOUDN'T CHANGE WIDTH
  </div>
  <div class='side-content'>
    THIS IS A SIDE CONTENT AREA THAT SHOUDN'T CHANGE WIDTH

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or like this to keep 2 of 3, 1 of 3. Do note that you need to set both *flex-grow* and *flex-shrink*, as the *flex-shrink* defaults to `1` and will kick in when there is no space left (distribute the negative space)

```
.main-content {
  flex: 2 2 0;                     /*  changed  */
  background-color: yellow;
  min-width: 0;                    /*  added  */
}

.side-content {
  flex: 1 1 0;                     /*  changed  */
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 0;                    /*  added  */
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.content {
  padding-top: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main-content {
  flex: 2 2 0;                     /*  changed  */
  background-color: yellow;
  min-width: 0;                    /*  added  */
}

.side-content {
  flex: 1 1 0;                     /*  changed  */
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 0;                    /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<h2>
Normal behaviour
</h2>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='main-content'>
    MAIN CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class='side-content'>
    SIDE CONTENT
  </div>
</div>


<h2>
Not proportional content
</h2>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='main-content'>
    THIS IS A MAIN CONTENT AREA THAT SHOUDN'T CHANGE WIDTH
  </div>
  <div class='side-content'>
    THIS IS A SIDE CONTENT AREA THAT SHOUDN'T CHANGE WIDTH

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```